# Reducing sorting time on a complex query in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

So i have this query

```
 with table1_group1 as materialized(
    select rh.data_id, rh.uuid,
    coalesce(c.name, (select "name" from group1 where "default" = true)) parsed_contractor
    from table1 rh
    left join group1 c on c.name = rh.group1
    group by rh.data_id, 2, 3
),
table1_verifications as materialized (
    select rh.data_id, rhcn.parsed_group1,
    count(vh) filter (where vh.result = 'true' and (vh.cargo_status = 'full' or vh.cargo_status is null) and vh.delivery = true) as successful_delivery_count,
    count(vh.uuid)                                            as verifications,
    count(vh.uuid) filter (where vh.result = 'false')         as unsuccessful_verifications
    from table1 rh
    join table1_group1 rhcn on rhcn.uuid = rh.uuid
    left join verification_history vh on rh.uuid = vh.vehicle_record_uuid
    group by rh.data_id, rhcn.parsed_group1
),
latest_per_group1 as materialized(
    select distinct on (rh.data_id, rhcn.parsed_group1) 
    rh.data_id, rhcn.parsed_group1 group1,
    rh.uuid, rh.inspection_list_name,
    r.uuid is not null and rh.expiration_time > now() currently_active,
    case when b.uuid is not null then 'black' else rh.status end as status
    from table1 rh
    join table1_group1 rhcn on rhcn.uuid = rh.uuid
    left join table3 b on b.record_uuid = rh.uuid
    left join table2 r on rh.uuid = r.uuid
    order by rh.data_id, rhcn.parsed_group1, rh.created_ts desc
)
select
rhcn.parsed_group1 group1,
coalesce(lpc.inspection_list_name, v.vehicle_type) as inspection_list_name,
rh.data_id,
lpc.status,
vh.successful_delivery_count,
exists(
select uuid from revocation rev
where rh.data_id = rev.data_id
and rev.expiration_time > now())                          as currently_revoked,
lpc.currently_active,
vh.verifications,
vh.unsuccessful_verifications,
string_agg(distinct coalesce(rh.driver_name, '-'), ', ')  as driver_name,
lpc.uuid
from table1 rh
join table4 v on rh.data_id = v.data_id
join table1_group1 rhcn on rhcn.uuid = rh.uuid
join latest_per_group1 lpc on rh.data_id = lpc.data_id
and rhcn.parsed_group1 = lpc.group1
join table1_verifications vh on rh.data_id = vh.data_id and
rhcn.parsed_group1 = vh.parsed_group1
group by 1, 2, rh.data_id, 4, lpc.uuid, 7, vh.successful_delivery_count,vh.verifications,
vh.unsuccessful_verifications
```

And it has a execution plan like this

```
    "GroupAggregate  (cost=16740.53..16818.88 rows=1 width=177) (actual time=249.485..268.757 rows=9704 loops=1)"
"  Group Key: rhcn.parsed_contractor, (COALESCE(lpc.inspection_list_name, v.vehicle_type)), rh.data_id, lpc.status, lpc.uuid, lpc.currently_active, vh.successful_delivery_count, vh.verifications, vh.unsuccessful_verifications"
"  CTE record_history_contractor_name"
"    ->  HashAggregate  (cost=1917.34..2026.00 rows=10866 width=55) (actual time=10.067..12.119 rows=10866 loops=1)"
"          Group Key: rh_1.uuid, COALESCE(c.name, $0)"
"          InitPlan 1 (returns $0)"
"            ->  Seq Scan on group1  (cost=0.00..1.24 rows=12 width=32) (actual time=0.010..0.011 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                  Filter: ""default"""
"                  Rows Removed by Filter: 23"
"          ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=1.54..1861.77 rows=10866 width=55) (actual time=0.064..7.030 rows=10866 loops=1)"
"                Hash Cond: (rh_1.group1 = c.name)"
"                ->  Seq Scan on table1 rh_1  (cost=0.00..1764.66 rows=10866 width=30) (actual time=0.017..2.772 rows=10866 loops=1)"
"                ->  Hash  (cost=1.24..1.24 rows=24 width=32) (actual time=0.040..0.041 rows=24 loops=1)"
"                      Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB"
"                      ->  Seq Scan on group1 c  (cost=0.00..1.24 rows=24 width=32) (actual time=0.015..0.017 rows=24 loops=1)"
"  CTE table1_verifications"
"    ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=6422.63..6775.77 rows=10866 width=63) (actual time=85.415..94.441 rows=9704 loops=1)"
"          Group Key: rh_2.data_id, rhcn_1.parsed_group1"
"          ->  Sort  (cost=6422.63..6449.79 rows=10866 width=655) (actual time=85.407..89.565 rows=12481 loops=1)"
"                Sort Key: rh_2.data_id, rhcn_1.parsed_group1"
"                Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 1704kB"
"                ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=2282.16..2537.19 rows=10866 width=655) (actual time=12.835..17.560 rows=12481 loops=1)"
"                      Hash Cond: (vh_1.vehicle_record_uuid = rh_2.uuid)"
"                      ->  Seq Scan on verification_history vh_1  (cost=0.00..219.08 rows=2808 width=632) (actual time=0.031..2.531 rows=2808 loops=1)"
"                      ->  Hash  (cost=2146.34..2146.34 rows=10866 width=55) (actual time=12.718..12.719 rows=10866 loops=1)"
"                            Buckets: 16384  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 786kB"
"                            ->  Hash Join  (cost=1900.49..2146.34 rows=10866 width=55) (actual time=3.354..10.644 rows=10866 loops=1)"
"                                  Hash Cond: (rhcn_1.uuid = rh_2.uuid)"
"                                  ->  CTE Scan on table1_group1 rhcn_1  (cost=0.00..217.32 rows=10866 width=48) (actual time=0.000..4.605 rows=10866 loops=1)"
"                                  ->  Hash  (cost=1764.66..1764.66 rows=10866 width=23) (actual time=3.282..3.282 rows=10866 loops=1)"
"                                        Buckets: 16384  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 715kB"
"                                        ->  Seq Scan on table1 rh_2  (cost=0.00..1764.66 rows=10866 width=23) (actual time=0.018..1.891 rows=10866 loops=1)"
"  CTE latest_per_group1"
"    ->  Unique  (cost=4616.17..4697.67 rows=10866 width=100) (actual time=49.350..51.416 rows=9704 loops=1)"
"          ->  Sort  (cost=4616.17..4643.34 rows=10866 width=100) (actual time=49.348..49.871 rows=10866 loops=1)"
"                Sort Key: rh_3.data_id, rhcn_2.parsed_group1, rh_3.created_ts DESC"
"                Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1526kB"
"                ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=3518.26..3887.74 rows=10866 width=100) (actual time=9.119..15.989 rows=10866 loops=1)"
"                      Hash Cond: (rh_3.uuid = r.uuid)"
"                      ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=1908.22..2194.83 rows=10866 width=96) (actual time=5.929..10.629 rows=10866 loops=1)"
"                            Hash Cond: (rh_3.uuid = b.record_uuid)"
"                            ->  Hash Join  (cost=1900.49..2146.34 rows=10866 width=80) (actual time=5.876..9.412 rows=10866 loops=1)"
"                                  Hash Cond: (rhcn_2.uuid = rh_3.uuid)"
"                                  ->  CTE Scan on table1_group1 rhcn_2  (cost=0.00..217.32 rows=10866 width=48) (actual time=0.003..0.824 rows=10866 loops=1)"
"                                  ->  Hash  (cost=1764.66..1764.66 rows=10866 width=48) (actual time=5.807..5.807 rows=10866 loops=1)"
"                                        Buckets: 16384  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1012kB"
"                                        ->  Seq Scan on table1 rh_3  (cost=0.00..1764.66 rows=10866 width=48) (actual time=0.021..3.854 rows=10866 loops=1)"
"                            ->  Hash  (cost=5.66..5.66 rows=166 width=32) (actual time=0.046..0.046 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                                  Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 8kB"
"                                  ->  Seq Scan on table3 b  (cost=0.00..5.66 rows=166 width=32) (actual time=0.019..0.041 rows=166 loops=1)"
"                      ->  Hash  (cost=1496.13..1496.13 rows=9113 width=16) (actual time=3.181..3.182 rows=9113 loops=1)"
"                            Buckets: 16384  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 556kB"
"                            ->  Seq Scan on table2 r  (cost=0.00..1496.13 rows=9113 width=16) (actual time=0.014..2.235 rows=9113 loops=1)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=3241.10..3241.10 rows=1 width=157) (actual time=248.922..250.305 rows=10866 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: rhcn.parsed_group1, (COALESCE(lpc.inspection_list_name, v.vehicle_type)), rh.data_id, lpc.status, lpc.uuid, lpc.currently_active, vh.successful_delivery_count, vh.verifications, vh.unsuccessful_verifications"
"        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1913kB"
"        ->  Hash Join  (cost=2942.26..3241.09 rows=1 width=157) (actual time=184.588..189.834 rows=10866 loops=1)"
"              Hash Cond: ((rhcn.uuid = rh.uuid) AND (rhcn.parsed_group1 = lpc.group1))"
"              ->  CTE Scan on table1_group1 rhcn  (cost=0.00..217.32 rows=10866 width=48) (actual time=10.069..10.747 rows=10866 loops=1)"
"              ->  Hash  (cost=2941.11..2941.11 rows=77 width=210) (actual time=174.505..174.507 rows=12333 loops=1)"
"                    Buckets: 16384 (originally 1024)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 1854kB"
"                    ->  Hash Join  (cost=1134.94..2941.11 rows=77 width=210) (actual time=163.983..170.545 rows=12333 loops=1)"
"                          Hash Cond: (rh.data_id = v.data_id)"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on table1 rh  (cost=0.00..1764.66 rows=10866 width=36) (actual time=0.021..1.531 rows=10866 loops=1)"
"                          ->  Hash  (cost=1134.14..1134.14 rows=64 width=245) (actual time=163.956..163.958 rows=9704 loops=1)"
"                                Buckets: 16384 (originally 1024)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 1356kB"
"                                ->  Hash Join  (cost=834.69..1134.14 rows=64 width=245) (actual time=145.559..160.447 rows=9704 loops=1)"
"                                      Hash Cond: ((vh.data_id = v.data_id) AND (vh.parsed_group1 = lpc.group1))"
"                                      ->  CTE Scan on table1_verifications vh  (cost=0.00..217.32 rows=10866 width=88) (actual time=85.418..96.757 rows=9704 loops=1)"
"                                      ->  Hash  (cost=671.70..671.70 rows=10866 width=157) (actual time=60.114..60.115 rows=9704 loops=1)"
"                                            Buckets: 16384  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 926kB"
"                                            ->  Hash Join  (cost=425.84..671.70 rows=10866 width=157) (actual time=51.938..57.676 rows=9704 loops=1)"
"                                                  Hash Cond: (lpc.data_id = v.data_id)"
"                                                  ->  CTE Scan on latest_per_group1 lpc  (cost=0.00..217.32 rows=10866 width=145) (actual time=49.354..53.184 rows=9704 loops=1)"
"                                                  ->  Hash  (cost=310.93..310.93 rows=9193 width=12) (actual time=2.565..2.565 rows=9193 loops=1)"
"                                                        Buckets: 16384  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 526kB"
"                                                        ->  Seq Scan on table4 v  (cost=0.00..310.93 rows=9193 width=12) (actual time=0.028..1.503 rows=9193 loops=1)"
"  SubPlan 5"
"    ->  Seq Scan on revocation rev  (cost=0.00..78.30 rows=1 width=0) (never executed)"
"          Filter: ((rh.data_id = data_id) AND (expiration_time > now()))"
"  SubPlan 6"
"    ->  Seq Scan on revocation rev_1  (cost=0.00..74.40 rows=14 width=7) (actual time=0.075..0.524 rows=9 loops=1)"
"          Filter: (expiration_time > now())"
"          Rows Removed by Filter: 1551"
"Planning Time: 1.814 ms"
"Execution Time: 273.485 ms"
```

The problem im having is that over half of the time is spent on sorting the data. I dont have any indexes beyond primary key index. The query started with execution time of over 500ms. With some modifications and fixes i got it to this result. Occationally i get execution time of 160ms. But on average its somewhere 250-300ms.

Right now the dataset is relatively small. Biggest table here has about 12000 rows, for now. But it can be expected to reach many hundred thousands. This query is used in conjuction with paging (limit offset), but also there is a need to know the total amount of rows.

Comment: Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 1704kB" , your work_mem is too small for this sort. Change it to a larger setting, 10MB for example, and see if the disk sort is gone. I would probably try to rewrite this query, you're collecting data from a single table in four different locations.

Comment: I have tried rewriting. Only CTE i could remove is the 2nd one. 3rd CTE usecase is very spesific and ihave not found a better way to do it. 1 CTE reduces the amount of times i have to doe the grouping. BEfore it was inlined and the performance was horrible, this actually improved the performance.

Comment: @FrankHeikens also i have tryed finding a better solution for the first CTE, but so far this seems to be the only one.

Comment: @FrankHeikens increasing work_mem had minute improvements, somewhere around 20-30ms.